# How to export csv file in laravel 9

Tags: laravel, csv, export-to-csv

How can I export a csv file in laravel 9.

```
    $fileName = 'file.csv';
    $callback = function() use($records, $fileName) {
        $date = (date("Y-m-d h:i:s"));
        $fp = fopen($fileName, 'w');
        fwrite($fp,"Export Data\nDate:".$date."\n\n\n");                
        foreach ($records as $fields) {
            fputcsv($fp, $fields);
        }
            fclose($fp);
    };
    $headers = array(
        'Content-Type' => 'text/csv',
        "Content-Disposition" => "attachment; filename=$fileName",
        "Pragma"              => "no-cache",
        "Cache-Control"       => "must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0",
        "Expires"             => "0"
    );        
    return response()->download($fileName, 'file.csv', $headers);
```

I have used code provided above to create a csv file, which is working fine and a correct file is being created, but the response I am getting in js front in browser is just the content of files.

`console.log(result)` gives response below

> Export Data

> Date:2022-04-20 04:20:69

> first_name,last_name,primary_email .....

How can I make the file download in browser?

Comment: ```return response()->download($fileName, 'file.csv', $headers);``` this fetches and responds the file content. If I echo this it responses file headers

Comment: Show your JS side, I think the problem is there. You need to tell the JS that it's a downloadable bloob data...something like:
.success(function(data){
  var binaryData = [];
  binaryData.push(data);
  var link=document.createElement('a');
  link.href=window.URL.createObjectURL(new Blob(binaryData, {type: "application/csv"}));
  link.download="students.csv";
  link.click();
})

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just had to put in some JS code to make it download
Here is the code I used.

```
    // Ajax request above this
    let result = response;
    const url = window.URL.createObjectURL(new Blob([result]));
    const link = document.createElement('a');
    var today = new Date();
    var date = today.getFullYear()+'-'+(today.getMonth()+1)+'-'+today.getDate() +"_"+ today.getHours() + today.getMinutes() + today.getSeconds();
    link.setAttribute('download', 'Export_Data_'+date+'.csv');
    link.href = url;
    document.body.appendChild(link);
    link.click();
```